# не срабатывает условия if в php

Tags: php

на openserver, делаю форму регистрации, форма работает, ошибки заполнения не обрабатывает

```
<?php
define(DB_HOST, '127.0.0.1');
    define(DB_USER, 'root');
    define(DB_PASSWORD, '');
    define(DB_NAME, 'test_db');





    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    if ($connection == false){
        echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!<br />';
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }

if (isset($_POST['submit']))/* && isset($_POST['password']))*/{
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
    $age = (int)$_POST['age'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $consent = $_POST['consent'];

    $error = false;
    if(empty($login)){
        echo  'Введите логин' ;
        $error = true;
    }
    if(empty($password)){
        echo  'Введите пароль' ;
        $error = true;

    if($password != $password2){
            echo 'Введенные пароли не совпадают' ;
            $error = true;
        }

    if($age == "" ){
            $error = true;
            echo  'Введите Ваш возраст' ;

        }

    if($age < 5 or $age > 100 ) {
            $error = true;
            echo   'возраст введен не верно' ;

        }

     if(empty($email)){
            echo  'Введите Ваш email' ;
            $error = true;;
        }

     if($consen == ''){
            echo  'Необходимо принять пользовательское соглашение' ;
            $error = true;
        }
        else{
            echo  "все хорошо";
        }}

       if ($error){
        echo 'есть ошибки';

       }else{

        $query_insert = "INSERT INTO users (login,password,age,email) VALUES 
       ('$login','$password','$age','$email')";
        $result_insert = mysqli_query($connection,$query_insert);

        if ($result_insert){
            $smsg = "Регистрация прошла успешно";
        }else{
            $fsmsg = "Ошибка";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Вот сама форма:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST">
        <?php if (isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-sucsess" role="alert"><?php echo $smsg; ?></div><?php } ?>
        <?php if (isset($fsmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><?php echo $fsmsg; ?></div><?php } ?>

        <h2>Registration</h2>
        <label>Логин:</label>
        <input type="text" name="login" class="form-control" placeholder="login" required="" ><br />
        <label>Пароль</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required=""><br />
        <label>Пароль повторно</label>
        <input name="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password2" required=""><br />
        <label>Возраст</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" placeholder="age" required=""> <br />
        <label>email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required=""><br />
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="consent"><a href="../consent.html">Я согласен на обработку персональных данных</a></label><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit">register</button>
        <a href="index.php">Main</a>

    </form>
```

Comment: Приведите код в порядок

Comment: это даже не код, а кусок вырванный из контекста)

Comment: что за `trim(empty(...))`, или `$_POST[1] == $_POST[2]` или `$$error` ?.

Comment: спасибо за коменты, постарался более подробно выложить код и исправить ошибки, осталось понять, почему не меняется переменная $error